# Bash - if/elif statement logic reporting back incorrectly

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep

I have a script that checks for a list of hosts in the hosts file, connects and then checks a file to see what the output is, if the output is two specific strings, then the bash script reports that the process has failed.

I've written what looks to me like it should work no issue, I've even tried it without the script running on interpreter and it returns what I expect, however when running it in a script it does not give the desired feedback.

It instead reports that host #2's process has failed, when in reality, it can't connect to host #2.

**Code**

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE='InternalAL2'
touch $FILE
BADPROCESS=()
for ip in $(cat /etc/hosts | grep serverAL2.[9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | awk {' print $2 '})
do ssh -n -f $ip -i ~/.ssh/personal.ssh "sleep 1; cat /etc/internalstate.txt | grep Status" > $FILE.txt
if cat $FILE.txt | grep "NOT RUNNING" ; then
   echo "NOT RUNNING detected on $ip"
   BADPROCESS+=($ip)
elif cat $FILE.txt | grep "STOPPED" ; then
   echo "STOPPED detected on $ip"
   STOPPED+=($ip)
else
   echo "ALL OK ON $ip"
fi
printf "$ip checked \n"
done
```

**Hosts file**

```
serverAL2.9000 <--- NOT RUNNING in file
serverAL2.9001 <--- Unreachable, timed out
...
```

**Output**

- Inside $FILE is 'Status NOT RUNNING'
- It reports 'ALL OK on serverAL2.9000' when it should report 'NOT RUNNING'
- It then tries to connect to 'serverAL2.9001', fails and reports NOT RUNNING on 'serverAL2.9001'
- All other hosts return if the process is running or not, fine.

I don't know why it is jumping ahead before checking the file contents

Comment: My apologies M.M - I've included the shebang

Comment: FYI -- `awk '/serverAL2.[9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ { print $2 }' </etc/hosts` is not only a more efficient way to write your `cat | grep | awk` pipeline, but also much less buggy. (The current code will pass `grep` the names of any files matching `serverAL2.[9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` to the `grep` command if any such files exist in your current directory instead of passing that literal string as a pattern). Even with that fixed, though, it runs afoul of [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: @Evert, ...keep in mind that the exit status of a pipeline is that of the last command in it (unless `pipefail` is enabled), and that `grep` has a nonzero (false) exit status if it doesn't match any lines.

Comment: If you can't connect to the host, then the file will be empty. If the file is empty, you count it as "all ok" because it doesn't contain any of the phrases.

Comment: @thatotherguy But I CAN connect to the host, as mentioned above, it's host #2 that I can't connect to that it returns the error for && the file contains NOT RUNNING after connecting to host #1

Comment: If you want to trace flow control, run with `PS4=':${LINENO}+' bash -x yourscript` to track every command invoked, and compare the actual commands run with the ones you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately one of the junior guys didn't get the FYI that I was developing a monitoring script and restarted the process manually so it now reports fine... If you guys can see anything glaringly wrong with my script I'll take it into consideration for why #1 reported OK when it was faulty

Comment: A couple of general things then.  Indenting the code inside a loop makes it easier to read/support.  Avoid UPPERCASE variable since the shell itself uses a large number of these.  Its safer to always enclose filename variables inside double quotes since they might contain whitespace, e.g. `"$FILE.txt"`, `touch "$FILE"`.